# Another Laravel Token Mismatch Exception issue

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have an application which uses AJAX quite a bit on a Laravel 5.3 application. I have some pages that are behind authentication and some that are not. The ones that are inside of authentication are working fine. The one that is outside (public facing) are giving me a the infamous `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68`. In order to attach the token to the AJAX header, I am using this...

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

And it is working because when I make a request, I can see this...
[image]

...but the tokens are not matching. When I go to the framework file `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` and do a `dd()` on the session token and the token that was passed, they do not match.

Things I have tried:

1. Clearing Cache (views, config, cache)
2. Changing session driver from
   file to Redis
3. Using `csrf_field()` instead of AJAX headers

I cannot figure out why this is not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you look closely your CSRF-TOKEN and XSRF-TOKEN in the cookie are not same. So, this could be one of the reasons that you are having the mismatch in the token.

Comment: @Samundra The framework looks for the header as `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. Plus, it works on other pages.

`Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`


`$token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');`

Comment: It looks as though Laravel stores a token which is generated from a random string into the session.  Then compares the token passed in for each request to the one generated in the session.  Make sure whatever route you are currently on is behind the `web` middleware group which sets up the session appropriately `routes/web.php`.

Comment: @user3158900 I tried that and it is still not working. I cleared all the caches too, but same thing.

Comment: so, your best bet would be to put a breakpoint and debug step by step and see where you get the error. Check to see if you pass that `X-CSRF-TOKEN` match or not?

Comment: @Samundra The answer that you posted has the exact method that I did just that. The part of my question about using `dd()` to compare the `$sessionToken` and `$token`. They do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, I finally figured it out. I am using BrowserSync for livereload, which proxies all my requests to `localhost:3000/*`. When I was testing the public side, I was visiting it through the original domain name and not proxied through browsersync's `localhost:3000` so that was causing session issues.

Basically, if you have BrowserSync running and you try in use your site not through browsersync, you can get token mismatch errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this code of laravel [Github Link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#L102-L123)

```
/**
 * Determine if the session and input CSRF tokens match.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    $sessionToken = $request->session()->token();

    $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

    if (! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
        $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
    }

    if (! is_string($sessionToken) || ! is_string($token)) {
        return false;
    }

    return hash_equals($sessionToken, $token);
}
```

It checks for the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` and also tries to check for `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. You can also try to send the `_token` from the ajax. I hope this helps you.

Comment: The code they're using is from the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf

Comment: @Samsquanch Yep, in my question, that is what I was talking about when I said - When I go to the framework file Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class and do a dd() on the session token and the token that was passed, they do not match.
It is that exact method. What am I missing.

Comment: Does your code gets through `! $token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')` ?

Comment: @Samundra It does not pass that if statement because my header is set to `X-CSRF-TOKEN` instead of `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. I make it to the final `return` statement.

Comment: one more check, What do you get when you do `dd($session->get('_token'));` in `Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php` after line `104` just after `$session->start();` see [Github Link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php#L104)

Comment: @Samundra I get the session token. I added this to that same line - `$session->put('testing', $session->get('_token'));` and they match when I look at the session. It's almost like it is being changed when I make the AJAX request or something.

Comment: Maybe it sees AJAX request as a completely new request and initializes a new token. But needs more testing with that.  Lets put `dd` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php` after `line 94` in `! $this->has('_token')` check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126927/discussion-between-dericcain-and-samundra).